# how to copy PyObject * memory data to another memory address?

Tags: python, c

I'm working on a C program that has Python embedded.

The host program is multi processes, which communicate via shared memory (mmap).

I create a Python object (e.g., PyDict_New) in one process. How can I copy this data to shared memory so that the other process can obtain this data and convert to Python Object?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to pickle your Python object into a string and copy the string into the shared memory. Then, the other process would unpickle it back into a Python object. From [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

> “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is
>   converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse
>   operation, whereby a byte stream is converted back into an object
>   hierarchy.